# Sending <p> data to a popup on button submit

Tags: jquery, forms, popup, radio-button, submit

I have 3 radio buttons. In each of them there is a `<p>` tag with a small line of text. What I'm trying to achieve is getting the text from the chosen radio button and put in a pop up box when a user is clicking on the submit button.

This is the setup:

```
<label class="container">
  <p>some text here....</p>
  <input type="radio" name="yourmenu">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'popup'? Presumably an `alert()`? Please also add the JS code you've written yourself in an attempt to solve this. We're always happy to help debug code here at SO, but we're not here to write code for you.

Comment: Hey Rory, yeah I mean a `alert()`

Comment: get the text of radio button in onclick like following.. 
 var radiotext = $(this).parent("label").child("p").text();alert(radiotext);

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
$("form").on("submit",function(e) {
  var text = $("[name=yourmenu]:checked").prev().text();
  if (!confirm(text)) e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit if not confirming
});
```

A more elaborate version:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var text = $("[name=yourmenu]:checked").prev().text() || "Intet valg";
  if (text=="Intet valg") { // nothing selected
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(text);
    return;
  }
  if (!confirm(text)) e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit if not confirming
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="container">
    <p>Vil du have Pizza?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="yourmenu">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="container">
    <p>Vil du have Pasta?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="yourmenu">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: THANKS! Yeah that's exactly what i was trying to go for! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then

```
$("form").on("submit",function(e) {
  var textSelected=$('input:radio[name=yourmenu]:checked').prev('p').text();
  alert(textSelected);
});
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes thanks for hinting, I missed the clause to get the checked radio value. :)